# What am I logging in as when I type psql in the command line?

Tags: postgresql

If I just type `psql` I open up the program in my command line, right? Who am I logged in as? Am I then going to say as that user when I choose which database to go into afterwards?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Whoami? in postgres

Type

```
select user;
```

to know who you are

### Example in windows

```
c:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.5\pg_env.bat
C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.5>psql
Password:
psql (9.5.1)

postgres=# select user;
 current_user
--------------
 postgres
(1 row)
```

In this example the username is postgres because `pg_env.bat` sets `PGUSER=postgres`

### How i am in Linux

If you type `psql` postgres try to connect you with the same name of your OS user.

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.9.36-x86_64-linode85 x86_64)
Last login: Sat Sep 16 11:02:09 2017 
tute@codenautas-server:~$ whoami
tute
tute@codenautas-server:~$ psql
psql: FATAL:  role "tute" does not exist
tute@codenautas-server:~$
```

You can change it with the enviroment variable or sudoing it:

```
sudo -u postgres psql
# select user;
 current_user
--------------
 postgres
```

Comment: can you explain why you need `postgresq` in `sudo -u postgres psql` when you already have the `psql` part?

Comment: When you install postgres (with apt-get install) in Ubuntu the superuser `postgres` does not has password. In that way only a sudoer can connect to postgres (and only internally). That's as secure as the operating system. You can set a password for `postgres` but the first use must be `sudo -u postgres psql`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`psql`'s prompt](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-PROMPTING) for that.

For example:

```
\set PROMPT1 '%[%033[33;1m%]%x%[%033[0m%]%[%033[1m%]%n@%/%[%033[0m%]%R%# '
```

to show the prompt like `user@database=#`

Use [`psqlrc` file](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html#AEN100828) to set the prompt permanently.